# Multiple parameter classes with type dependency

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to promote my Aggregator type to a class and I can't figure out how to do it.

I have this:

```
data Aggregator a b = Aggregator { aggregate :: [a] -> b }
minMax = Aggregator (\xs -> (minimum xs, maximum))
```

and I would like something like :

```
class Aggregator (g a b) where
   aggregate :: g -> [a] -> b
```

So I can do things like :

```
data DoubleAggregator a b = DoubleAggregator ([a] -> b) ([a] -> b)

instance Aggregator (DoubleAggregator a b) where
     aggregate (DoubleAggregator f g) as = (f as, g as)
```

Which obviously doesn't work. I think I need either `MultipleParamTypeClasses` or `FamilyTypes` but I can't figure it out. I know, in that particular I don't really needed classes and could do just with `data Aggregator a b ...`, but I'm still interested in how to do it with classes. So how can I do it ?

Comment: I know you are specifically interested in handling this with classes, but it sounds more like a `fold` problem, even if you just used `data Aggregator a b. ...`, as it is it looks like the empty list isn't likely to be handled correctly.  You might want to look into `Monoid` and folds?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that your instance for `DoubleAggregator` is not well typed, since the output is `(b,b)` but the class declaration says that it must be `b`. So you either figure out a way to merge your two `b`s into one, which is probably not desirable, or make your output type depend on your aggregator type:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}

class Aggregator g where
  type Result x y z 
  aggregate :: g a b -> [a] -> Result g a b

data SingleAggregator a b = SingleAggregator ([a] -> b)
instance Aggregator SingleAggregator where 
  type Result SingleAggregator a b = b
  aggregate (SingleAggregator f) = f 

data DoubleAggregator a b = DoubleAggregator ([a] -> b) ([a] -> b)
instance Aggregator DoubleAggregator where
  type Result DoubleAggregator a b = (b,b)
  aggregate (DoubleAggregator f g) as = (f as, g as)
```

Note that the class does not mention `a` or `b`, since those are both free to be any types, and don't depend on the aggregator type. The type `Result` is a function of three things: the type of aggregator, and the types inside the aggregator. It's possible that your result will never depend on the input type, `a`, in which case you can write something like:

```
class Aggregator g where
  type Result x y 
  aggregate :: g a b -> [a] -> Result g b

....

  type Result SingleAggregator b = b

....

  type Result DoubleAggregator b = (b, b)
```

You can also do this with `MultiParamTypeClasses` and `FunctionalDependancies` but it is more complex and the types are harder to read, so in my opinion it is a worse solution, and I only include it for completeness.

```
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses, FunctionalDependencies, FlexibleInstances #-}

class Aggregator g a b r | g a b -> r where
  aggregate :: g a b -> [a] -> r

data SingleAggregator a b = SingleAggregator ([a] -> b)
instance Aggregator SingleAggregator a b b where 
  aggregate (SingleAggregator f) = f 

data DoubleAggregator a b = DoubleAggregator ([a] -> b) ([a] -> b)
instance Aggregator DoubleAggregator a b (b,b) where
  aggregate (DoubleAggregator f g) as = (f as, g as)
```

The main difference is the functional dependancy: `| g a b -> r`; which says that for there is one unique `r` that can exist for some `g a b`.

Answer (score 4):

In addition to using type families or functional dependencies (as in user2407038's answer) another alternative is to use a [GADT](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/GADT).

```
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs #-}

class Aggregator g where
    aggregate :: g a b -> [a] -> b


data SingleAggregator a b = SingleAggregator ( [a] -> b )

data DoubleAggregator a b where
    DoubleAggregator :: ([a] -> b) -> ([a] -> b) -> DoubleAggregator a (b, b)


instance Aggregator SingleAggregator where
    aggregate (SingleAggregator f) as = f as

instance Aggregator DoubleAggregator where
    aggregate (DoubleAggregator f g) as = (f as, g as)
```

Whether this is a better or worse alternative depends on your exact use-case but I find it much simpler in practice than the type class extensions.

The GADT approach also allows you to ditch the type class altogether if you want and just use a single algebraic type.

```
data Aggregator a b where
    SingleAggregator :: ([a] -> b) -> Aggregator a b
    DoubleAggregator :: ([a] -> b) -> ([a] -> b) -> Aggregator a (b, b)

aggregate :: Aggregator a b -> [a] -> b
aggregate (SingleAggregator f)   as = f as
aggregate (DoubleAggregator f g) as = (f as, g as)
```

However, probably the most "Haskell-y" way of approaching this was to have just a single `Aggregator` newtype and make that composable with the `Applicative` type-class. For example:

```
import Control.Applicative

newtype Aggregator a b = Aggregator { aggregate :: [a] -> b }

instance Functor (Aggregator a) where
    fmap f (Aggregator g) = Aggregator (f . g)

instance Applicative (Aggregator a) where
    pure = Aggregator . const
    Aggregator f <*> Aggregator x = Aggregator $ f <*> x
```

Now you can define simple aggregators like

```
minAgg = Aggregator minimum
maxAgg = Aggregator maximum
```

and then compose them into more complex aggregators using the `Applicative` interface

```
minMax = liftA2 (,) minAgg maxAgg
```

Comment: I really like that! Thank you (I might have finally understood what GADT are for :).

Comment: Thanks. :)  I also added an example that uses Applicatives which I think is the most commonly used pattern in problems like this.